# Retrieving ids of splitted list in R

Tags: r, list, split

Say I have a list, like so:

```
my.list <- list()

for (i in 1:100)
  {
  my.list[[i]] <- list(location = sample(paste0("Location", 1:5), 1, replace=T),
                       val1 = runif(100),
                       val2 = runif(30))
  }
```

Now I split it by location

```
loc <- sapply(my.list, function(x){x$location})
my.list.split <- split(my.list, loc)
```

Is there a way to associate each element of `my.list.split` to the original `my.list`, i.e., finding its ID in `my.list`?

Comment: This would be really easy if you used data frames rather than just lists. Is there a reason everything has to be a list?

Comment: @joran: yes, I actually have a few arrays in there, so I cannot really use a data frame (modified the example accordingly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to find the IDs:

```
IDs <- seq_along(my.list) # generate a vector of IDs

IDs.split <- split(IDs, loc) # split the IDs along loc
```

This returns a list which includes vectors of IDs for each `location`.

Comment: I knew there was an easy solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you give `my.list` some names, then your `my.list.split` will also have names which you can use to refer back, if necessary.

```
# Syntactically different, but functionally equivalent way of creating the list.
my.list<- lapply(1:100,function(x) list(location = sample(paste0("Location", 1:5), 1, replace=T),
                       val1 = runif(100),
                       val2 = runif(30)))
names(my.list)<-paste0('id_',seq_along(my.list)) # Added 
loc <- sapply(my.list, function(x){x$location})
my.list.split <- split(my.list, loc)
```

So, now everything has an unique id:

```
my.list.split[[1]]
# $id_11
# $id_11$location
# [1] "Location1"
# 
# $id_11$val1
#   [1] 0.997154684 0.348063634 0.373797808 0.569167679 0.417461443 0.799423830 0.147882721
#   [8] 0.489438012 0.292867337 0.072622654 0.583932815 0.060452664 0.083562011 0.613114462
# ....    
# $id_11$val2
#  [1] 0.68983774 0.41056046 0.18620312 0.61078253 0.85947881 0.50736945 0.01362270 0.70022800
```

Comment: This is also a good idea, although I guess @Sven solution is easier to manage (at least for my specific task).

Answer (score 1):

Another way if for some reason you don't want to set IDs first:

```
match(unlist(my.list.split, FALSE), my.list)
```

You can then set the names with `names()` or whatever if that's what you're trying to do.

---

`split()` divides your list into a nested list according to `loc`. `unlist()` with `recursive` set to `FALSE` will remove the items from `my.list.split` so that they are in the same shape as `my.list`. Then all you have to do is `match()` them to see which items refer to what indices in the original object.

Proof that the match is correct (should return `TRUE` unless I've made a horrible mistake):

```
ul <- unlist(my.list.split, FALSE)
m <- match(ul, my.list)
identical(my.list[m], unname(ul))
```